# Cookies present in network response header from Node.js backend but not available in application storage cookies tab

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies, setcookie

I'm attempting to create a basic cookie using express's res.cookie() function. However, I'm encountering an issue where the cookies aren't being properly set in the application tab. My setup consists of a React frontend and a Node backend.

Here's the version of the code I'm using for both the frontend and backend:

Frontend is at: http://localhost:3000/
Backend is at: http://localhost:5000/

**Backend Login controller**

```
const loginUser = async (req, res, next) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;
  if (!email || !password) {
    return next(new BadRequestError("Please provide email and password."));
  }

  const user = await User.findOne({ email }).select("+password");

   
   // Define cookie options
  const cookieOptions = {
    expires: new Date(
      Date.now() + process.env.JWT_COOKIE_EXPIRES_IN * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
    ), // Cookie expiration date
    httpOnly: true, // Cookie cannot be accessed by JavaScript/browser on the client side
  };

  // Set the JWT cookie in the response
  res.cookie("jwt_cookie", jwtToken, cookieOptions);

   res.send(user);
   };
```

**Backend cors config
**

```
app.use(cookieParser());
// ? Enable CORS middleware
app.use(
  cors({
    credentials: true,
    origin: "http://localhost:3000",
  })
);
```

**Frontend login service
**

```
const loginExistingUser = async (userCredentials, thunkApi) => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.post(
      "http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/v1/auth/login",
      userCredentials,
      { withCredentials: true }
    );
    return response.data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return thunkApi.rejectWithValue(error.response.data.msg);
  }
};
```

Although I observe the code in the network tab, the challenge lies in the fact that the code is not being stored within the Application/Cookies. Furthermore, it is not being transmitted alongside subsequent requests after the login process, which is the expected behavior.

I've been working on troubleshooting this issue for the past 24 hours, but unfortunately, I haven't been able to find a solution so far.

Comment: Is there an error message when you hover over the cookie in the Network tab?

Comment: Is the code all functioning fine? If the only issue is that the cookies aren't visibly present in the browser, that may be a security feature and not a bug.

Answer (score 0):

After investing 42 hours, I successfully got it to work using the following setup with the help of this video: [Setting up cookies in a React and Express App (locally and in production)[1].

To ensure the proper functioning and display of cookies in my application on Chrome, I had to include the following code in my frontend app's `package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "app_name",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "dependencies": {
    // ... other dependencies
  },
  "proxy": "http://127.0.0.1:5000",  // Added for proper communication
  // ... other configurations
}
```

However, for seamless deployment in production, it's essential to make additional adjustments on the backend side as well. These adjustments will ensure the continued functionality of the application in a production environment.

```
app.use(
  cors({
    origin:"your_frontend_url",
    credentials: true,
  })
);
```

Here are the cookie options for both development and production environments:

```
  const cookieOptions = {
      maxAge: 3 * 60 * 60 * 1000, // Set the maxAge in milliseconds,
      sameSite: "lax",
      httpOnly: true,
      secure: false,
    };

    // Set 'secure' option for the cookie if in production mode
    // ! Ensure this is set to 'true' before deploying to production
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
      console.log("PRODUCTION MODE");
      cookieOptions.secure = true; // Cookie will only be sent over HTTPS
      cookieOptions.sameSite = "none"; // Cookie will be sent for cross-site requests
    }
```

I trust this will be beneficial to others.

**References:**
[1]: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nviGhgtFbRo